# Написать план тестирования для простой программы

Tags: тестирование

Здравствуйте. Программе подаются на вход три стороны треугольника,  и исходя из них нужно определить тип этого треугольника.  Написать план тестирования

Comment: Какие бывают треугольники? Какие не бывают? План готов)

Comment: Извините,  а в чем смысл вообще тест-плана? Я не понимаю

Comment: Смысл в том, чтобы подобрать наиболее полный набор тестов, чтобы покрыть все возможные случаи.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Какие бывают треугольники?
   По сторонам:

   - Равносторонние
   - Равнобедренные, не являющиеся равносторонними
   - Разносторонние

   По углам:
   *если функция может вернуть список признаков, потому что они не исключают тех, что выше*

   - Остроугольные (все углы меньше 90)
   - Прямоугольные (Один угол 90)
   - Тупоугольные (Один угол > 90)
2. Какие не бывают?

   - a + b == c (вырожденный треугольник с нулевой площадью)
   - a + b > c